# For-loop logic in order to print an inputed character using scanf n number of times

Tags: c, loops, for-loop, scanf, control-flow

I've been trying to understand the logic behind this for loop but I've been unable to. The problem asks to input an integer `n` (number of test cases) followed by n number of characters with each characters denoting the day of the week. So I need to output the day n number of times.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int n, i;
    char ch;

    scanf("%d",&n);

    for (i = 0; i < 2 * n; i += 1)
    {
        scanf("%c", &ch);
        switch (ch)
        {
        case 'M':
            printf("Monday\n");
            break;
        case 'T':
            printf("Tuesday\n");
            break;
        case 'W':
            printf("Wednesday\n");
            break;
        case 'H':
            printf("Thursday\n");
            break;
        case 'F':
            printf("Friday\n");
            break;
        case 'S':
            printf("Saturday\n");
            break;
        case 'N':
            printf("Sunday\n");
            break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I don't understand the logic for `i<2*n`. So for example when I input `n=2` followed by characters `M M`, and `i` is initialized to `0`, the condition for `0 < 4` is checked which is true so the first character `M` is input, and `Monday` is printed once, now `i` is incremented to `1` and is checked against `1 < 4` which is true and is printed once again. Now it has already been printed twice, but according to the `i < 2 * n` logic shouldn't `Monday` get printed 4 times until `4 < 4` terminates the for loop?

But this logic somehow works correctly.

My logic for `i <= n`, for some reason does not work and only inputs and prints the character the one time. Where am I going wrong here?

Comment: You have spaces between your letters

Comment: Can you add your exact input, as well as the output you get, and the output you expected ? As @Jacob suggests, you probably have extra characters in your input (spaces or newlines, or ...).

Comment: Adding a `default` case where you `printf` the received value of `ch` would show you hints at what is happening.

Comment: The thing is the code works fine, but I just needed help to understand the logic used in the for loop, and how exactly the i<2*n condition prints the day that many number of times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`scanf("%c", &ch);` scans the character you input but the `\n` newline character, caused by the `enter`, remains on the buffer, (the same is true for the previous `scanf` in your code), this causes the for loop to run 2 times for every input: first, it scans the character itself and then the `\n`. This is the reason why your `for` loop needs to run 4 times instead of the 2 it should.

You will need to discard those `\n` characters. You can use `%*c` to discard them, then you can replace `n*2` with `n` in the `for` loop, the advantage is that the loop runs only half of the times you have now.

This works, not only for block input separated by space, but also for one at a time inputs.

[**Link to live sample**](https://onlinegdb.com/ByBK5rYX8)

```
//...
scanf("%d%*c", &n); //<-- dicard newline character

for (i = 0; i < n ; i += 1) {
    scanf("%c%*c", &ch); //<-- discard newline character
//...
```

Comment: Got it, since I'm only getting started with C and I never had to solve a problem that required me to input a number of test cases depending on integer, I did not think about the spaces that I was inputting while executing the program.Thanks!